# Lint doesn't detect "calling new methods on older versions" - what can be done?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Lately I wanted to look into the possibility of increasing backward compatibility for my app from API `16` to `14`.

**What I tried:**

To see what potentially needs fixing, I changed the `android:minSdkVersion` in the manifest to `14` and rebuilt the project. To my amazement, it built just fine (which was somewhat suspicious), so I set the `minSdkVersion` to `1` to see what happens. At this point, a few *warnings* sprung up in the manifest of type `Attribute unused on older versions`, but when trying to rebuild the project it finished successfully. I tried to `Analyze > Inspect code...` and it found no errors of this nature (even though there should be plenty). I additionally tried disabling and re-enabling the filter (see image) and restarting IntelliJ - but to no avail.

[image: Inspection settings]

**My questions:**

1. Could this be a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there a better way to test for backward compatibility?

Additional information:

- If it matters, I'm working with several other people on this project using a code repository (I thought I could possibly have downloaded some corrupt settings files, but I think I've excluded this scenario).
- My IntelliJ version is 13.1.4

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building with Gradle?

Comment: Your approach would only work if Lint is part of the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. I don't use IDEA directly (only in its Android Studio flavor), so I don't know if Lint is part of the plugin or not.

Comment: @kcoppock - negative, just plain IntelliJ (as far as I can tell). @CommonsWare - the option in the image appears under `Android > Android Lint` so I suppose it is part of the Android plugin...

Comment: Okay, so there's no build.gradle script. My theory was that your minSdkVersion might be being overwritten by the Gradle script. Could you try running just the API inspection? (Analyze > Run Inspection By Name... > Calling new methods on older versions). Make sure that the Inspection scope is your whole project, and that you don't have a filename filter that might be too restrictive.

Comment: @kcoppock - That worked :) thanks for the tip! (I guess I was only running it in the scope of the "main module"). It is still unclear to me why lint doesn't show it inside the files... This is a major pitfall and shouldn't compile imho (could lead to crashes, no?).... :\

Comment: See my latest answer update -- you probably need to enable that inspection for your Project Default inspection profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your Inspection Scope is set to your entire project:

[image: example]

The reason you're still able to compile just fine is that it is *absolutely acceptable* to call these newer methods, provided you specifically guard your calls with a version check. For example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // Hardware acceleration not supported -- do nothing!
}
```

And to prevent any warnings for this, you can annotate the calling method with `@TargetApi`, for example:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES_HONEYCOMB)
public void setLayerType(View view, int layerType) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        myView.setLayerType(layerType, null);
    } else {
        // Hardware acceleration not supported -- do nothing!
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, to get the warnings inline, ensure that this inspection is enabled on the Project Default Inspections profile:

[image: example]

Final EDIT: Also, make sure there are no `lint.xml` or `lint-rules.xml` defined somewhere which might be overriding the expected severity levels for these issues. See [the following link](http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/03/inspection-lint-and-intellij-rules.html) for more info.

Comment: The inspection is enabled (as can be seen in my screenshot), but these things are supposed to be displayed as errors, yet I see no lint messages in the files themselves (which is what bothers me the most).

Comment: You should probably look into moving to Android Studio at some point. For me, these show up as red error messages. (They will not, however, prevent your application from compiling).

Comment: Aren't they theoretically the same thing?

Comment: Android Studio typically has more features at any point in time. At some point they end up back in the plugin and back into IntelliJ but that can be a while. There may be some features specific to Android Studio.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I was too quick to accept the answer... I noticed just now that when looking for these problems in the entire project's scope it only found them in the "library modules" and not in the main module itself. Installed Android Studio 0.8.11 -> errors are still not showing. Created a new project from the sources (recreate workspace.xml and some other IDEA files) -> still no errors shown :(

Comment: Any chance you have a lint-rules file or similar which may be disabling that inspection? Otherwise, this could be a bug on the Windows version of IntelliJ, but I'd doubt that to be the case.

Comment: You are absolutely right! The culprit was a 'lint.xml' file that was filled with '<issue id="...." severity="ignore">'... Once deleted the errors started appearing. [The diagram on this page helped](http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/03/inspection-lint-and-intellij-rules.html). Feel free to add this to your answer :-)

Comment: Yay! Your link doesn't exist though. ;)

Comment: Posted the comment before I was done typing... This is what happens when you comment from the phone :p